# Property of Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a non-zero real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and two diagonal real matrices $D \in \mathbb{R}^ {n\times n}$ and $K \in \mathbb{R}^ {n\times n}$. Is the following equation holding?
$$D(A)^+K = (DAK)^+$$,
where $(\cdot)^+$ is the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse of $(\cdot)$.

Comment: notice that a matrix $K \in \mathbb{R}^ {n \times n}$ is a matrix of a size $n^{2} \times n^{2}$

Comment: @Jneven in my opinion a real matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns should be represented as $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, which has been used in academic papers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take it back to the definition of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:
$$DAK(DAK)^\dagger DAK = DAK$$
$$(DAK)^\dagger DAK(DAK)^\dagger = (DAK)^\dagger$$
and substitute your definition:
$$DAKDA^\dagger KDAK = DAK$$
$$DA^\dagger KDAKDA^\dagger K = DA^\dagger K$$
To which it is clear that only holds if $K = D^{-1}$, as this is not given, your statement is false. The correct equation would be:
$$K^{-1}A^\dagger D^{-1} = (DAK)^\dagger$$